# Read csv file with regular expression delimeter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv file like this:

```
x,y,z, vec, s2
1,2,3,(1,2,3),5
3,4,3,(4,5,3),8
```

I want read this file, vec as (a,b,c). when reading with pd.read_csv(filename), it is reading differently.

Comment: yeah, this really isn't a standard csv. You can usually specify a quotechar inside of which the delimiter is ignored, but here, you are using opening and closing parens. I highly suggest you fix whatever is generating this "csv"

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should load csv as a string, then split to list, finally transform list to dataframe.

```py
with open('test.csv') as f:
    csv = f.read()+'\n'
import re
import pandas as pd
reArr = re.findall('([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),(.*),([^,]+)\n',csv)
df=pd.DataFrame(reArr[1:],columns=reArr[0])
print(df)
```

|  | x | y | z | vec | s2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | (1,2,3) | 5 |
| 1 | 3 | 4 | 3 | (4,5,3) | 8 |

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```
with open(r'myFile.csv', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read().split('\n')

cols = data[0].split(', ') # Note there's a whitespace after the comma
dat = [i.split(', ') for i in data[1:]]
df = pd.DataFrame(dat, columns = cols)
```

However, keep in mind that this method returns your values as strings in the dataframe. It should be easy to convert all the singular numbers to integers with the `apply()` function and `int()`, but the tricky part is converting those tuples to actual tuples. For that, do this...

```
from ast import literal_eval
df['vec'] = df['vec'].apply(literal_eval)
```